# How to make a spaghetti plot in ggplot R for categorical variables, and colour each line by ID?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm trying to make a spaghetti plot for some time series data and am having some trouble - my attempts so far do not show a separate line for each individual.

Individuals were sampled twice (in July and October) and at each time point I tested whether or not they were infected with nematodes (Yes/No).

I want to make a graph with "Nematode infection status" on the Y axis and "Month" (or "Time" if I have to make it numeric?) on the X axis.

My data looks like this:

```
ID Month Time nematode_infected  
1  July   1   Yes
1  Oct    2   Yes
2  July   1   Yes
2  Oct    2   No
3  July   1   No
3  Oct    2   Yes
```

ID, Month, and nematode_infected are all factors

And my current code to graph it looks like this:

```
ggplot(recaptures_combined_long, aes(x=Time, y=nematode_infected, group=ID))+
  facet_wrap(~RELATIVEAGE)+
  labs(x="Month", y="Nematode infected?") + geom_line()
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jykXF.png)  (note that I have ~70 different IDs so there should be 70 lines on this graph, but there are only 4 per graph)

If I use "colour = ID" instead of "group = ID", [I get this mess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSW71.png)

[What I want is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jO9w.jpg), but with each line (each ID) a different colour:

Any idea how I could go about producing this graph? Thank you!

Edit -  the solution was:

```
ggplot(recaptures_combined_long, aes(nematode_infected, Month, color = as.factor(ID), group = ID) )+
  facet_wrap(~RELATIVEAGE)+ labs(x="Nematode infected?", y="Month")+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.2))+theme_classic()  +
  coord_flip() + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
df <- read.table(text = 
"ID Month Time nematode_infected  
1  July   1   Yes
1  Oct    2   Yes
2  July   1   Yes
2  Oct    2   No
3  July   1   No
3  Oct    2   Yes", 
h = T)


library(ggplot2)           

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(Month, nematode_infected, color = as.factor(ID), group = ID))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That kind of works, but when I do it with my whole dataframe I still can't see the separate lines for each ID. I just googled whether I can jitter the lines and it turns out I can, using geom_line(position=position_dodge()). This, plus your advice, did the trick!